# "Who am glad? " or "Who is glad? " question select?

Tags: questions

> I am glad.

What question of mentioned above to this sentence is correct? I want to ask about subject.

Comment: _Who am glad?_ is not a valid sentence. _Am_ is only appropriate with _I_.

Answer (score 1):

"Who am glad" is never correct, grammatically or logically (if you try to put *am* in there, you probably know the answer because *am* always refers to first-person singular).

> Who is glad?

Answer (score 0):

Correct: Who is glad?

'Who is glad?' - 'I am glad.' ('Am' is used with 'I')

'Who are glad?'-'We are glad.'

Be= am, is, are (present)

= was, were (past)

I am, I was, You are, You were, He is, He was, It is, It was, They are, They were,

---

Joke

A- 'Who is the manager?'

B- 'I is the manager.'

A-'Are you?'

B- 'Yes, I are.'

A- 'Who am glad?'

B- 'I am glad.'